# Reading audited relations with Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-envers

We are using Hibernate Envers (4.3.5.Final) with Spring Data Envers (0.2.0.RELEASE).

With the following entity setup I can not read the list of C on B (which is always empty), when I query a specific version of entity A:

```
@Entity
@Audited
class A {
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Audited
class B {
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<C> cList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Audited
class C {
    private Integer id;
}
```

The following tables are generated:

A, A_AUD, A_B, A_B_AUD, B_C, B_C_AUD

My guess is, that this is not really possible, because the auditing tables lack the information of the relation from A to C, but I am not sure. Can you confirm this or give me a hint how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this using Hibernate Envers 5.2.7 and there wasn't any problem.  Perhaps this was an old bug that has been fixed or it's an issue with the Spring Data Envers implementation:

```
final EntityA a = auditReader.find( EntityA.class, aId, revision );
assertNotNull( a );
assertTrue( !a.getBList().isEmpty() );
for ( EntityB b : a.getBList() ) {
  assertTrue( !b.getCList().isEmpty() );
  for( EntityC c : b.getCList() ) {
    assertNotNull( c );
    System.out.println( c );
  }
}
```

The above prints out my `EntityC` instance just fine.